# Git Python Pycharm - Get current branch

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I try to get the current checkout git branch in my pycharm project. Pycharm is working on a copy of the repository in a temp folder of a remote server. So the command:

```
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
branch = repo.active_branch
return branch.name
```

is not working, because it is looking in the copied temp folder it is currently working in if it is a git repository. Is there any other way to get the currently checkout branch of pycharm with python?.

Comment: Please advise the following link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manage-branches.html

Comment: Hmm, cant see a python command to get the current branch in pycharm

Comment: Why do you need a python command? You can just switch branches directly from the GUI of pycharm. If you don't want to use the GUI, you can always use the terminal and issue git commands - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html

Comment: Are you writing a tool to be used with PyCharm or what is this project about?